# Allocation of memory for a pointer to a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

When I allocate memory for a structure in C using the malloc function, why don't I have to cast the function since its returning type is void* and not the structure I want?
So why this:

```
Str *str = malloc(sizeof(Str));
```

and not this:

```
Str *str = (Str*)malloc(sizeof(Str));
```

?

Comment: Why do you wrap your `malloc` calls in additional parenthesis?

Comment: Sidenote: `Str* str = (malloc(sizeof(Str));` -> `Str* str = malloc(sizeof(Str));`

Comment: In c, (void *) can be converted to any other pointer type without an explicit cast. This the cast is not necessary in this case